# Google Apps Script MailApp Not Sending Email To Script Owner

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I've set up a script to take information from a Google Form and email that information to multiple people using Google Apps Script.  What it does not do, however, is email the owner of the script.  I'd like the owner of the script to also receive the email and it does not send it to the owner.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here's a snippet of the code...

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    replyTo: 'no-reply',
    bcc:'email1@example.com',
    cc: 'email2@example.com',
    subject: 'School Nurse Office Visit Notification - '+firstName+' '+lastName+' - '+dateOnly,
    htmlBody: '<h3>This is an auto-generated response of your E-Nurse Pass Submission.</h3>'+
    '<p>Here is the information you submitted:</p>'+
    '<b>Date/Time Submitted: </b>'+dateAndTime+'<br>'+
    '<b>Staff Email: </b>'+email+'<br>'+
    '<p><b>Student Name: </b>'+firstName+' '+lastName+'<br>'+
    '<b>Student Grade: </b>'+grade+'<br>'+
    '<b>Room Number: </b>'+room+'<br>'+
    '<b>Student Complaint: </b>'+complaint+'<br><br>'+
    '<b>Additional Info: </b>'+additionalInfo+'<br><br>'+
    'Feel free to reach out to me if you have any questions.<br><br>'+
    '<p>Thanks!<br>'+
```

Answer (score 0):

MailApp is not really reliable, use GmailApp instead.

NOTE: GmailApp methods are not identical to MailApp methods checkout the docs -> https://developer.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app

Related (from Stack Overflow)

- [Google marks emails sent from spreadsheet with MailApp.sendEmail as phishing scam](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15985154/1595451)
- [Google forms auto-email not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25306948/1595451)